# two separate elements with background image - i need both backgrounds be behind both element

Tags: html, css, background-image

i have two separate elements in my page, witch every one of them has a background image. i want that the both backgrounds will be behind both elements. I've been sitting on it for two weeks and can not get over it. need some help..!

[image]

The red arrows (in the photo in link above) are the two elements. Two lines of text. I want the background of both of them to be in the back and to see the two lines in their entirety

this is my css:

```
 .first{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    right: 3%;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;    
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(255, 131, 30);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 30;
    background: url('http://127.0.0.1:3000/img/brush.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 115%;
    background-position: center;
}

.second{
    margin: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 8%;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 6.5rem;
    color: orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 30;  
    background: url('http://127.0.0.1:3000/img/brush.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 110%;
    background-position: center;  
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: try to use `z-index` with `position:relatieve` to wantted selector

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or removed at a later stage (rendering your question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

As @לבני מלכה said, use `z-index` with `position: relative` option. 
Maybe this small lecture will be helpful [[CSS Tricks] z-index BY SARA COPE](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

Also, you should attach your code - that could be useful.

Comment: with z-index i can play with a complate element. i can push the second line back but it not help me because then firs line will hide the second

Comment: i update the question - add my css code. the html its spmle div with text

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value `z-index` of first element

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/hw8pz76e/3/

```css
 .first{
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    right: 3%;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;    
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: rgb(255, 131, 30);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 32;
    background: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 115%;
    background-position: center;
}

.second{
     width:150px;
   height:150px;
    margin: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 8%;
    font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 6.5rem;
    color: orange;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 30;  
    background: url('https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 110%;
    background-position: center;  
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: not. it pushs the second line back but it not help me because then firs line will hide the second. i need somehow make separate z-index count for backgroug and z-index count for the element. @לבני מלכה thanks alot for caring!!

Comment: Set `margin-bottom` to `.first`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f4r96h8k/1/    i need both of the text lines to be seen. i don't care about the images - they have same color.

Comment: thanks. i can just move them away like you suggest - its not what i meant but i will try to play with the gap between the line and pray for it to work equally on all browsers.

Comment: it looks you pray very hard to the Rabbi :)